# Getting Current Data from KendoUI TreeView

Tags: json, treeview, datasource, kendo-ui

I'm using a kendo UI tree with a remote data source from a JSON file.
I have a button on the tree page which gets the current data of the tree,sends it through a POST to a server and the server saves the current data to the JSON file so as the next time I reload the page,the changes I made will be kept.That's what I want to happen.

So I know the current data of the tree is in:

```
$("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").dataSource.data()
```

Which means the data changes real time in there for example when someone drag and drops a node of the tree.

My problem starts when this data doesn't seem to change when I drag and drop nodes inside the tree,and only changes when I drag and drop a node on the root level of the tree and even then it doesn't do it correcly as the node should be moved in there as well but instead the node gets copied,leaving the past node in the tree as well...

For Example I have this tree:

[image: Starting Tree]

If I make a drag and drop change like this:

[image: Change 1]

And I send the data,save it and reload the change isn't made at all!

PS:Even when I view the current data after the change before sending it,I see that there is no change on the data at all even though I did a change visualy with a drag and drop.So it doesn't have to do with the sending,saving and the server.

On the other hand,if I make a change like this:

[image]

I can see in the current data that the moved node is added in the end of the data indeed but it is not deleted from it's initial position within the data!So if i send the current data to the server,save it and then refresh I get the result:

[image]

The code for viewing and sending the data is:

```
function sendData() {
            var req = createRequest();
            var putUrl = "rest/hello/treeData";
            req.open("post", putUrl, true);
            req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
            var dsdata = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").dataSource.data();
            alert(JSON.stringify(dsdata));
            req.send(JSON.stringify(dsdata));

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState != 4) {
                    return;
                }
                if (req.status != 200) {
                    alert("Error: " + req.status);
                    return;
                }
                alert("Sent Data Status: " + req.responseText);
            }
        }
```

Is this a Bug or am I doing something wrong?Has anyone been able to see the current data changing correctly on every drag and drop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First and most important you have to use the latest version of KendoUI (Kendo UI Beta v2012.3.1024) still in beta but is where they have solved many problems.

Then, when you create the kendoTreeView you have to say something like:

```
    tree = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource :kendo.observableHierarchy(data),
        dragAndDrop:true
    }).data("kendoTreeView");
```

Here the important is **not** using directly data array but wrapping it with `kendo.observableHierarchy`.

Then you will have the data updated with the result of drag & drops.

Comment: Indeed it worked perfectly!Thank you very much!!
Btw do you know any way to handle the expand arrows next to the folders?Because I guess by some bug in the beta,expand arrows show on nodes without children too..(Also the arrows dont appear to be expanded on initiallizasion to folders which are expanded,but well glitches are supposed to exist in a beta i guess)

Comment: If you want to remove the extra arrow on those nodes that do not have children is just not defining `items` on it. If there is `items` even if it is empty then you get arrows. Not sure if it is a *feature* or a *bug*

Comment: In theory, expanding all nodes should be `tree.expand(".k-item");` but for some reason (bug?) it doesn't (always) work. I've found two workarounds: 1. define in your json an 'expanded' field and set it to 'true'. 2. execute `tree.expand('.k-item')` twice!!.

Comment: Thx again!About the unexpanded arrows it seems that the data array saves the expanded status as well so no problem there,just awesome!
About the extra arrows,it seems that the empty `items` field is added automatically by the data array if no `items` field exists so it seems I can't do anything there..Any idea for a workaround apart from searching the json file and deleting the `items:[]` fields everytime??Any other way known to control the arrows?

Comment: That is true for me too,if the JSON doesn't have `items` field then I don't get the arrow either!The problem is that when I drag and drop a node,if the node didn't have an `item` field at all,then kendo adds automatically `"items":[]` on the node when it writes the node on the new position!

Comment: to remove the expanded arrows use    
    schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "MenuItemId",
                        children: "MenuItemChildren",
                        hasChildren: (e) => {
                            //this removes arrow next to items that do not have children. 
                            return e.MenuItemChildren && e.MenuItemChildren.length > 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

Answer (score 0):

For me in addition to OnaBai answer I had to use the sync function on the save method. I am using Type Script.

```
 this.treeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                data: kendo.observableHierarchy([]),//Thanks OnaBai

                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "MenuItemId",
                        children: "MenuItemChildren",
                        hasChildren: (e) => {
                            //this removes arrow next to items that do not have children. 
                            return e.MenuItemChildren && e.MenuItemChildren.length > 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

public save() {
        this.treeData.sync().done(() => {
            console.log("sync data"); 
            var myType = this.treeData.view();

            this.$http.post("/api/TreeViewPicker", myType)
                .then((response) => {

                }); 
        });



    }
```