# How to get value of KendoUI TreeView

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, treeview, kendo-ui

Firstable sorry for my English. I've problem with KendoUI TreeView control on ASP.NET MVC4.

```
<div class="treeview-back">
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeview-left")
    .DragAndDrop(true)
    .Events(ItemAction)
    .BindTo(Model)
)
```

I got treeview and binded event OnDrop:

```
function OnDrop(e) {
dropped = GetValueFromTags(e.destinationNode.innerHTML);
inDrag = !inDrag;
OnHover();
e.setValid(e.valid && id > 10000);
if (e.valid && id > 10000) {

    var webMethod = "/Sitemap/UpdateData";
    var data = $("div.treeview-back").find("span.items").text();
    //var data = $("div.treeview-back").data("kendoTreeView").dataSource.data();
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webMethod,
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        converters: {
            'text json': true
        },
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log("error: " + data);
        }
    });
}
```

}

And my action in Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateData(IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel> data) 
    {
        // some database operations here
        return Json(data);
    }
```

I would like to send current state of my treeview to action. Problem is current method is sending null. I was able to send datasource but it was orginal data (that what i binding to control on start), not the current.

Thanks for help,
Łukasz

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309896/getting-current-data-from-kendoui-treeview?rq=1